# Python stops looping through list after some iterations

Tags: python, arcpy

For my work I had to write a python script to produce several maps showing similar data for different schools. I am using a cursor to loop through my list and this is actually working quite well for the first 28 schools in my list. However, then I get an error message while exporting the next map to a pdf file.

> AttributeError: PageLayoutObject: Error in executing ExportToPDF

I also tried to Export the map only to a jpeg file which works a bit longer but also stops after ca. 50 iterations with the same error.

I have no idea why my script is working for the first 28 iterations and stops then. Does anyone have an idea? May it be that Python can't save so many files to the Folder I'm directing to? Or is the memory filling up or anything? What can I do against that?

I'm pretty new to Python an programming in General so that I don't know how to solve this Problem.

Here is part of my code (which might help):

The beginning with initilizing the Cursor:

```
Schulliste = "filepath/Schulliste_PrSt.csv"
fields = ('Schule_Nr', 'Schule_Name') 
CursorSchule = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Schulliste, fields) 
for row in CursorSchule:
*[a lot of tasks to set up the map]*
```

the end of the code to save the maps as pdf and jpeg file:

```
# Karte exportieren
if SF == "STS":
  arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mapdoc, "filepath/Einzugsgebiet_{0}.pdf".format(row[0])) 
  arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mapdoc, "filepath/Einzugsgebiet_{0}.jpg".format(row[0])) 
elif SF == "G":
  arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mapdoc, "filepath/Einzugsgebiet_{0}.pdf".format(row[0]))
  arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mapdoc, "filepath/Einzugsgebiet_{0}.jpg".format(row[0]))
```

The total code for Loop:

```
for row in CursorSchule:
    #define mapdoc and dataframes
    mxd = "filepath/Standard_Einzug.mxd"
    mapdoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd)
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mapdoc)[0]
    df_Sus = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mapdoc)[1]


    #define new layers
    lyrSchule = arcpy.mapping.Layer("filepath/FHH_Schulen_SJST_2014_SingleSym_red.lyr")
    lyrNachbarsch = arcpy.mapping.Layer("filepath/FHH_Schulen_SJST_2014_SingleSym_blue.lyr")
    lyrEinzug = arcpy.mapping.Layer("filepath/FHH_StatGeb_2011_GradCol.lyr")

    #define legends
    legend1 = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mapdoc, "LEGEND_ELEMENT", "Legende1")[0]
    legend2 = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mapdoc, "LEGEND_ELEMENT", "Legende2")[0]

    #add table for every School with table join 
    folder = "filepath/"
    joinTable = join(folder, "Daten_{0}.csv".format(row[0]))
    arcpy.AddJoin_management(lyrEinzug, "StatGeb_Nr", joinTable, "StatGeb_Nr")
    arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion(lyrEinzug, "filepath")

    #add saved shapefile
    lyrEinzug = arcpy.mapping.Layer("GPL0.shp")
    legend1.autoAdd = False
    legend2.autoAdd = True
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, lyrEinzug)
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mapdoc):
        if lyr.name == "GPL0":
            lyr.name = "Gebietsbezogen"

    #Change symbology of the layer to graduated Color
    lyrEinzug = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mapdoc, "Gebietsbezogen")[0]
    sourceLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("filepath/StatGeb_Label_Halo_Symbol.lyr")
    arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df, lyrEinzug, sourceLayer, False)
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    lyrEinzug = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mapdoc, "Gebietsbezogen")[0]

    #Change symbology classes
    fieldlist = arcpy.ListFields("filepath/GPL0.shp")
    valueField = fieldlist[-1]
    lyrEinzug.symbology.valueField = valueField.name
    lyrEinzug.symbology.classBreakValues = [0, 5, 10, 20, 40, 70, 100]
    lyrEinzug.symbology.classBreakLabels = ["unter 5% der SuS", "5 bis unter 10% der SuS", "10 bis unter 20% der SuS", "20 bis unter 40% der SuS", "40 bis unter 70% der SuS", "über 70% der SuS"]
    lyrEinzug.transparency = 50

    #Data Frame Extent
    queryField = fieldlist[7]
    fieldname = queryField.name
    delimfield = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(lyrEinzug, fieldname)
    attribute_query = delimfield + " = {0}".format(row[0])
    lyrEinzug.definitionQuery = attribute_query
    df.extent = lyrEinzug.getSelectedExtent(False)
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

    #add labels
    labelField = fieldlist[9]
    if lyrEinzug.supports("LABELCLASSES"):
        for lblclass in lyrEinzug.labelClasses:
            lblclass.showClassLabels = True
    lblclass.expression = "\"<FNT name='Arial' size='3'><CLR green = '112' blue = '255'>\"" + " & [" + labelField.name + "] & " + '"</CLR></FNT>"'
    lyrEinzug.showLabels = True
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

    #select specific school
    fieldSchule = "Schule_Nr"
    delimfieldSchule = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(lyrSchule, fieldSchule)
    querySchule = delimfieldSchule + " = {0}".format(row[0])
    lyrSchule.definitionQuery = querySchule
    arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion(lyrSchule, "filepath/02_GIS-Daten")
    lyrSchule = arcpy.mapping.Layer("GPL0_1.shp")
    legend1.autoAdd = True
    legend2.autoAdd = False
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, lyrSchule, "TOP")
    lyrSchule = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mapdoc, "GPL*")[0]
    sourceLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("filepath/Schule_Labels_Halo.lyr")
    arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df, lyrSchule, sourceLayer, False)
    lyrSchule.name = "{0} ({1})".format(row[1], row[0])

    if lyrSchule.supports("LABELCLASSES"):
        for lblclass in lyrSchule.labelClasses:
            lblclass.showClassLabels = True
            lblclass.expression = '"%s" & [Schule_Nam] & "%s"' % ("<BOL><FNT name='Arial' size='3'><CLR red = '255'>", "</CLR></FNT></BOL>")
    lyrSchule.showLabels = True
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

    #select neighboring Schools within 1.5 km
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis("filepath/buffer", 1500)
    lyrBuffer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("buffer.shp")
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(lyrNachbarsch, "WITHIN", lyrBuffer)
    arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion(lyrNachbarsch, "filepath")
    lyrNachbarsch = arcpy.mapping.Layer("filepath/GPL0_2.shp")
    legend1.autoAdd = True
    legend2.autoAdd = False
    arcpy.mapping.InsertLayer(df, lyrSchule, lyrNachbarsch, "AFTER")
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mapdoc):
        if lyr.name == "GPL0_2":
            lyr.name = "Nachbarschulen (<1,5km)"
    lyrNachbarsch = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mapdoc, "Nachbar*")[0]
    sourceLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("filepath/FHH_Schulen_SJST_2014_SingleSym_blue.lyr")
    arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df, lyrNachbarsch, sourceLayer, True)

    #if selected School is elementary School, also only select neighbouring elementary Schools
    SC = arcpy.SearchCursor(lyrSchule)
    for Schule in SC:
        SF = Schule.getValue("Schule_SF")
    fieldform = "Schule_SF"
    delimfield1 = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(lyrNachbarsch, fieldform)
    query_SF = delimfield1 + "= 'G'"
    lyrNachbarsch.definitionQuery = query_SF
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

    del SC, Schule

    #Labels for schools
    fieldname = "Schule_Nr"
    delimfield2 = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(lyrNachbarsch, fieldname)
    query_Nachbar = delimfield2 + "<> {0}".format(row[0])
    if lyrNachbarsch.supports("LABELCLASSES"):
        for lblclass in lyrNachbarsch.labelClasses:
            lblclass.className = "Schulname"
            lblclass.SQLQuery = query_Nachbar
            lblclass.expression = '"%s" & [Schule_Nam] & "%s"' % ("<FNT name='Arial' size='3'><CLR red = '100' blue = '100' green = '100'>", "</CLR></FNT>")
            lblclass.showClassLabels = True
    lyrNachbarsch.showLabels = True
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

    #Change text
    #Titel
    Titel = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mapdoc, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "Titel")[0]
    Titel.text = "Einzugsgebiet Jahrgänge 1-4"

    #Legende
    style_StatGeb = arcpy.mapping.ListStyleItems("USER_STYLE", "Legend Items", "Einzug")[0]
    style_Schulen = arcpy.mapping.ListStyleItems("USER_STYLE", "Legend Items", "Schule")[0]
    legend1.updateItem(lyrSchule, style_Schulen)
    legend1.updateItem(lyrNachbarsch, style_Schulen)
    legend2.updateItem(lyrEinzug, style_StatGeb)
    legend1.elementPositionY = 25
    legend2.elementPositionY = 11.0
    legend2.elementPositionX = 1.5

    #number of pupils
    lyrSchuldaten = arcpy.mapping.Layer("filepath/Schulliste_PrSt.lyr")
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df_Sus, lyrSchuldaten)
    lyrSchuldaten = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mapdoc, "Schulliste*")[0]
    querySchule = delimfield2 + "= {0}".format(row[0])
    lyrSchuldaten.definitionQuery = querySchule
    df_Sus.extent = lyrSchuldaten.getSelectedExtent(False)
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

    #Infotext
    Infotext = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mapdoc, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "Infotext")[0]
    Infotext.text = "nicht darstellbar: SuS aus dem Umland \n \nAggregation: Statistische Gebiete \nKlassenberechnung: manuell gesetzte Intervalle \nDatenbezug: Wohnort der SuS \nDatenauszug: 10.01.14 \nKartengrundlage: DISK60"
    Infotext.elementPositionY = 1.73

    #Export map
    if SF == "STS":
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mapdoc, "filepath/Einzugsgebiet_{0}.pdf".format(row[0]))
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mapdoc, "filepath/Einzugsgebiet_{0}.jpg".format(row[0]))
    elif SF == "G":
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mapdoc, "filepath/Einzugsgebiet_{0}.pdf".format(row[0]))
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mapdoc, "filepath/Einzugsgebiet_{0}.jpg".format(row[0]))


    #delete shapefiles
    arcpy.Delete_management("GPL0.shp")
    arcpy.Delete_management("GPL0_1.shp")
    arcpy.Delete_management("GPL0_2.shp")
```

*EDIT:*

I tried to save the jpeg files with a higher solution today which led to the error message a lot earlier than before which might underline that it has something to do with the available memory?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with Python. Please try to find out which file is returning the error, maybe the file is corrupted, or you ran out of memory. Python stops looping because it gets an error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's Kind of what I expected... I know which file is returning the error but it has nothing to do with the file itself. Running the process only for that file works totally fine. I probably can't Change anything about the Memory, right?

Comment: The the single run is fine it could be many things. Hard to say from here. Are you sure that you can process the single file? When you tested it, did you run the exact same command as the script?

Comment: Yes I ran the exact same script but I shortened my list before that, so that only the one case was processed... I also tried it with another list, and again I get the same error after ca. 25 maps are produced

Comment: Well the memory problem is only in two cases: either you are saving the data in an external drive with low storage memory, or your computer has no more disk storage memory. However I don't think it's that and I cannot see anything wrong with your code. You can try to print out some logs and paste it here. Also you can try to add more code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try fiddling with the variables that your loop is getting from the 28th map. It looks like you're using a csv file for all this, maybe copy the column of a working map into the row that's not working, just to confirm whether or not it's a memory issue. Once you've confirmed that triple check all the values from your 28th school. It looks like one of them might be invalid when trying to convert to a pdf.

Comment: It works totally fine when I only calculate everything for this one school, as I said before. I tried it again, it has nothing to do with the variables